Omnet++ cyclical results of measurements
I have a problem with my ping results. They come out cyclically every 3 the same, not really different. I don't know where this problem comes from. (My PingApp with ICMP set up is good). (I have RIP network with 6 routers and 2 hosts H1 and H2).
enter image description here
I have tried also with txPk and rxPk packets, but results were the same of rtt from PingApp.
